# How to include in GHResponse all nodes from a straight line

Tags: graphhopper

When requesting a route between to points, the container GHResponse doesn't include all the points in the way, i.e, if the route is a line some points are omitted. How can I retrieve all the points/nodes that are in the line?

Comment: Why would you need the points between a straight line? Couldn't you create the necessary points? We reduce the response from unnecessary data and make it cheaper to be transmitted over the wire. You can disable this behaviour but this is not part of the official documentation and will not add points but keep potential points already there from OSM

Comment: Ok. So where this pre-processing is done? What is the threshold to add or not add the point? Can i change this threshold?
Thank you